# What does Ed Sheeran say at the beginning of "Gold Rush"?

Tags: lyrics

I was listening to the album, and solely in the right side (for one second) there’s someone saying something before Ed breaks into the actual course.

Here’s [the song on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2Py0mXX7FM).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like "Whatever you want, mate" or "Whenever you want, mate". The second makes more sense at the start of a [take](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Take) in the studio - i.e. "Start playing whenever you want".